# refreshing service references won't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, service-reference

I'm working on a .net Mail Client/Service in Visual Studio 2010.

The problem I experience right now is that if I change my Service, the client does not notice these changes. This is how I proceed:

I change one of the interfaces in the service and then refresh the service reference on the client side. There's this little window with the progress bar that shows me that the reference is refreshed now.

But when I wanna use the new implementation I still don't see any changes. For instance:

earlier: `void putFile(byte[] contents, String name);`

now: `void putFile(myFile file);`

I then refreshed the service reference and tried to use the method on the client side. But all I get is the old interface.

Comment: How are you "refreshing" the service? Should be Right Click -> "Update Service Reference"

Comment: yeah, I do it like that

Comment: Where is your client pointing in order to get the WSDL? Are you sure is pointing to the updated wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

So, I would try this:

Use [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) to see if it also sees the old definiton. If it does, you didn't update the service properly. If it doesn't, then there's some weird caching going on - completely remove the service reference, manually check all files have been removed and and add it back in again.

Comment: hmm.. I also noticed some differences in the Service Reference. But I don't know what they mean. the IMailService has the new implementation, but then there's also a MailServiceClient which does have the old implementation.. http://i.cubeupload.com/QtsSNW.jpg

Comment: I think that's where the problem lies. I just can't find out how to update this MailServiceClient.. Tried deleting everything but that didn't work either..

Comment: Did you figure it out in the end?

Answer (score -1):

Inseat of refreshing, click "Update Service Reference" by right click on the Servicne name.
[image]

Comment: that's what I did. Sorry my visual studio is in German, I wasn't sure about the exact menu translations

Comment: So you down rated my answer for this because you have tried this :)

Comment: actually I didn't rate anything on this site ^^'

Comment: what platform are you using? if you are using Visual Studio or any java IDE , make sure you have build the project.